# To save files or folders to ExternalStorageDirectory just works after restarting my cellphone

Tags: android

I want to create new folder or a file, but everything is shown after restarting my cellphone, my android version is 6.0. and I've added permissions(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, camera,record,..,it depends on my need )
It's very important to me to create immediately.

This is my current code for recording:

```
AudioSavePathInDevice = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                   .getAbsolutePath() + "/" +
                                    "AudioRecording.3gp";
...
MediaRecorder mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(AudioSavePathInDevice);
```

What should I do now?

Comment: also it doesn't work on less than version 6

Comment: I've discovered sth amazing, I changed my cellphone from English to Persian, and it's shown without restarting my cellphone, but it still doesn't work for creating new folder in gallery.